# How to Refresh particular cell in tableview and store that changed data to show later on same tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4

I have implemented tableview with paging facility. I want to update cell image with like image when I click on button action, if I did not refresh whole tableview how to save that updated particular tableview data. When I scroll back to that cell again.

```
let indexPathRow:Int = self.toreloadindexint 
let indexPosition = IndexPath(row: indexPathRow, section: 0)                                           
self.tablall.reloadRows(at: [indexPosition], with: .fade)
//......tableview cell data for reload data that i get from api..........
       if updateintoflike == 0
        {
            // print("after updation on cell count",self.toreloadindexint)
            var favcounts = arrayfeedwebcounts[indexPath.row] as! Int //"data"
            lblfav?.text = "0"//String(favcounts)
            favcounts = 0
            print("fav..", lblfav?.text)
        }
        else
        {
           // print("after updation on cell count",self.toreloadindexint)
            lblfav?.text = ""

            var row: Int = indexPath.row
            arrayfeedwebcounts.remove(at: row)
            arrayfeedwebcounts.insert(updateintoflike as AnyObject, at:row)
            var addedcontt = arrayfeedwebcounts[indexPath.row] as! NSNumber
            lblfav?.text = String(updateintoflike)
            print("label fav..", lblfav?.text)
       }
```

Comment: I have added this code for refresh row but after refresh ahows wrong image and data

Comment: You need to maintain the like state in your data source.

Comment: yes that's issue i get wrong count in label even i check refresh state by new variable in cell that show incorrect value @ PGDev

Comment: Add more code so I can debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain the state of your `UITableViewCell` in your `tableView's` `dataSource` model. I'll try to elaborate that through an example.

**1.** Let's assume you `model` looks something like:

```
class Post {
    var isLiked = false
    var likeCount = 0
}
```

**2.** Next, you need to create the custom `UITableViewCell` such that it modifies the `dataSource` and the `UI` as per the `button` *action*, i.e.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!

    var post: Post?

    func configure(with post: Post) {
        countLabel.text = "\(post)"
        likeButton.isSelected = post.isLiked
    }

    @IBAction func likeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        if let post = post {
            post.isLiked = sender.isSelected
            if sender.isSelected {
                post.likeCount += 1
            } else {
                post.likeCount -= 1
            }
            countLabel.text = "\(post.likeCount)"
        }
    }
}
```

**3.** Finally, the `UITableViewDataSource` methods will be,

```
class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    var posts = [Post]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.configure(with: posts[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

In the above code, whenever the `likeButton` is pressed, the `UI` and the `dataSource` will be updated. So, whenever the `cell` is displayed again, you'll see the last updated data automatically.

There is no need to reload the `tableView` or `cell` everytime the `likeButton` is tapped. Reloading will only result in the extra overhead.

Comment: Yes, i got solution that can resolve that incorrect data problem. thank you for your model structure.@PGDev

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :-**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: rowNumber, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
```

**if it not work then try this**

```
 self.tableView.beginUpdates()
 let indexPath = NSIndexPath.init(row:  self.selectedTag, section: 0)     
 self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
 self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

If it not working then please comment so I check too.

Comment: i did it there is code from my tableview cell is it also anything wrong with it ?
 let row: Int = indexPath.row
                arrayfeedwebcounts.remove(at: row)
                arrayfeedwebcounts.insert(updateintoflike as AnyObject, at:row)
                var addedcontt = arrayfeedwebcounts[indexPath.row] as! NSNumber
                lblfav?.text = String(updateintoflike)
                print("label fav..", lblfav?.text)

Comment: My code is for reload Particular Row of tableview and your code is insert and delete row is it right .?

Comment: Okay I think your code is correct can you elaborate the issue so I can help you